# Qml import local Files as qualifier doesn't work

Tags: javascript, qt, import, directory, qml

the following code is and illustration for my problem , the qml file im importing and qualifying as EventListner is highlighted in blue , but it doesn't work when i use it.

*main.qml:*

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
import "/qtrealis/untitled15/EventListner.qml" as EventListner
Window {
visible: true
width: 640
height: 480
title: qsTr("Hello World")
Button{
   onClicked:EventListner.color="blue";
}
```

*EventListner.qml:*

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
Item {
property string color: "dark"
onColorChanged: console.log("event received!")
}
```

[image: illustration]

Comment: What are you trying to achive? If you want to have it as a singleton, declare it as such in the qmldir-file. Otherwise create an instance. For this you don't need to explicitly import it, as it is in the same directory in your qrc. A qml-file is no js library.

Comment: how do i declare it as a singleton in the qmldir-file ?? , i'am trying to emit a signal from main.qml, and receive it in the EventListner.qml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have singleton instance of the `EventListener` you will need to add

```
pragma Singleton
```

as first line of your `EventListener.qml`

```
pragma Singleton

import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
Item {
    property string color: "dark"
    onColorChanged: console.log("event received!")
}
```

Then you need a file called `qmldir` in the directory where you have the `EventListener.qml` with the content:

```
singleton EventListener 1.0 EventListener.qml
```

Finally you can use it in the `main.qml` by importing it:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
import '.' // To import Singletons you need to explicitly import the directory
           // that holds the qmldir file
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    Button {
       onClicked: EventListener.color = "blue";
    }
}
```

More on the `qmldir` file can be found in the documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-modules-qmldir.html

> **Note:** If you are using the `qrc`-resource system you need to make sure that the `qmldir`-file is added to it. (Right-Click on the qml.qrc, Add/Add Existing (depending on whether it is already created)). Otherwise you need to use the import statement:
>   `import 'file:/path/to/the/directory` (Maybe absolute path necessary)

Comment: i have another question , what if i wanted to use multiple files , as singletons , i tryed it and it didnt work :/ , so what should i do ?